# Help me identify this card playing board game.

Tags: identify-this-game

Hello all you card game aficionados!

Back in the day, my Mom & Dad played a card game that used this game board (see image).  I do not remember the name, OR, how to play. I don't really need the name of the game, but that would help. The rules are what I need. Does anyone recognized the game?

Incidentally the game board is about 2 x 2 masonite. My Dad cut up a deck of cards and glued them in the order illustrated, then shellacked the surface etc. voila.
I would be happy to share any info collected. I remember that the game was fun and unique.

Hope anyone can help.

Cheers

Grayley McWatters
Barrie, Ontario

[image]

Answer (score 13):

A board game of sorts, popular in the Eastern USA, known as One-Eyed Jack, Jack Foolery, Jack Off, and Sequence.

**Setup**
Players: 2-4 (4 players is done in teams of 2)
Materials:
The board you've pictured
Two standard playing card decks, Jokers removed (104 cards total).
A set of 50 chips for each player.

**Play**:
Shuffle the 104 card deck, dealing 7 cards to each player in a two player game, 6 in a three, or 5 in a four. The cards not dealt are retained as a drawing stock for the course of the game.
Game is played in turn, clockwise starting with the player after the dealer.
Each players turn proceeds as thus: Play a card from your hand, place a counter of your color on the indicated square, then draw a card from the stock.

**Special Cards**: since their aren't jacks on the field, they cause a special action to occur.
Two Eyed Jack: Wild Card
One Eyed Jack: Remove an opponents counter.

Win Condition: Form two uninterrupted lines of 5 counters, with one allowed intersection.

Source: http://www.pagat.com/misc/jack.html
Google Fu: board game 10x10 playing cards

Comment: For completeness sake, it might be a good idea to mention which two jacks don't have board pieces.

Comment: None of the jacks are represented on the board. The eight jacks in the draw deck have special effects, determined by the number of eyes visible.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like sequence.You play the cards and place chips on the board. The goal is to get 4 in a row